# Property of ring $R$ which is inherited by $R[X]$ but not by $R[[X]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, power-series

$\require{cancel}$

Recently I have witnessed the proof of the fact that if $R$ is noetherian so are $R[X]$ and $R[[X]].$

From what I read on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Properties) I guess that if $R$ is $\cancel{\text{local ring}}^*$/integral domain so are $R[X]$ and $R[[X]].$

> Can you cook up some property of $R,$ such that the ring of polynomials $R[X]$ also has that property and the ring of formal power series $R[[X]]$ does not?

**Note.** I am not looking for differences between $R[X]$ and $R[[X]]$ which hold for arbitrary commutative ring $R.$

EDIT$^*$. user26857 pointed out that $R[X]$ do not have to be local if $R$ is local. Clearly for every point $a\in k^n$ ideal $(x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$ is maximal in $k[X]$.

Comment: Being a finitely generated $R$-algebra

Comment: @PavelČoupek You are right. Not module, but algebra

Comment: Possibly relevant: If $a$ is a regular element (= non-zerodivisor) of $R$, then $X-a$ is a regular element of $R\left[X\right]$ (by virtue of being a monic polynomial), but not necessarily a regular element of $R\left[\left[X\right]\right]$ (see Example 6.3 in my *Regular elements of a ring, monic
polynomials and “lcm-coprimality”*, http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/algebra/regpol.pdf ). This is not an intrinsic property of the **rings** $R\left[X\right]$ and $R\left[\left[X\right]\right]$, but might nevertheless help for whatever you're trying to achieve with them.

Comment: Probably more useful: $R\left[\left[X\right]\right]$ has a huge Jacobson radical (it contains all multiples of $X$ as well as the Jacobson radical of $R$).

Comment: @darijgrinberg This second example holds for any rings $R$? I am asking cause the question was to cook up some property of $R$ and not to point out differences between $R[X]$ and $R[[X]]$ for arbtrary $R.$

Comment: @darijgrinberg But wiki says that $R[[X]]$ is integral domain if $R$ is integral domain. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Properties

Comment: Oops! I didn't want to assume that $a$ be regular. (I got this confused with another example later on, that disproves a more subtle assertion.)

Comment: If $R$ is a UFD, so is $R[X]$, but $R[[X]]$ may not be. For examples of this kind, look at Samuel's lectures on UFDs, TIFR notes.

Comment: @Mohan This it the answer I was looking for. I had a look into Samuel's lectures on UFD's (http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr30.pdf), but I can not find the fact that $R[[X]]$ may not be UFD.

Comment: @Mohan Really?! That seems pretty amazing...

Comment: @FallenApart The only consistent obvious thing to me is (already mentioned by darij) is that $X$ is in the Jacobson radical of $R[[X]]$ but not in that of $R[X]$.

Comment: @FallenApart There is a chapter on power series and this is more or less the first thing he does. See corollary 1 in the chapter on power series rings over factorial rings.

Comment: @Mohan I haven't known that UFD is the same as factorial ring. You should make an answer to this question, cause your example is perfect solution to my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One standard example is that if $R$ is a UFD, $R[X]$ is a UFD, but $R[[X]]$ may not be. Such examples can be found in P. Samuel's lecture notes on UFD, TIFR lecture notes. See the chapter on power series over factorial rings, corollary 1.

Comment: This is "standard", but too complicated. *Integrally closed* is much simpler. If $V$ is a valuation ring of rank $>1$ then $R[[X]]$ is not integrally closed.